# useContext causing blank screen

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-context

The app uses useContext for state management and axios for a get request to an API to receive data. Originally I was not using useContext but later realized state will be needed in multiple components later down the road and props would be messy. The app was working perfectly prior to using useContext now I am receiving a blank screen and no error messages.

ThemeContext.js

```
import {useState, useEffect, createContext} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
const ThemeContext = createContext()

const ThemeContextProvider = props => {

  const [students, setStudents] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)


  useEffect(()=>{
    getStudents()
  },[])

  const getStudents = async () => {
    try {
          const res = await axios.get('https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students')
          setStudents(res.data.students)
          setLoading(true)
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
  }

  return (
      <ThemeContextProvider.Provider value={{students, loading}}>
          {props.children}
      </ThemeContextProvider.Provider>
  )

}

export {ThemeContextProvider, ThemeContext}
```

Students.js

```
import {useContext} from 'react'
import {ThemeContext} from './themeContext'


const Students = props => {

  const {students, loading} = useContext(ThemeContext)  
 
  return (
    <div>
        {loading &&
         students.map((student) =>(
                <div className="student-profile-container">

                      <div className="student-profile-image">
                        <img key={student.id} src={student.pic} alt="student profile avatar"/>
                      </div>
                      <div className="student-profile-info">
                          <h1 className="student student-name">{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</h1> 
                          <p className="student student-info">Email: {student.email}</p>
                          <p lassName="student student-info">Company: {student.company}</p>
                          <p className="student student-info">Skill: {student.skill}</p>
                          <p className="student student-info">Average: {student.average}%</p>

                       
                      </div>
                    
                </div>
               
            ))
        }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Students;
```

Comment: If there is a blank page, it likely means there is an error in the console.  Did you check that for details about the error?

Comment: Error message is "Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `ThemeContextProvider`."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are mixing up `ThemeContext` and `ThemeContextProvider`. Changing the return value of `ThemeContextProvider` should fix your issue.

```
<ThemeContext.Provider value={{students, loading}}>
   {props.children}
</ThemeContext.Provider>
```